# Image size inside TextView

Tags: android, textview, android-image

I'm using this class to show an image inside a `TextView` with `Html.fromhtml()`

```
public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter {
    Context c;
    TextView container;
     MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
     FileCache fileCache;

    /***
     * Construct the URLImageParser which will execute AsyncTask and refresh the
     * container
     * 
     * @param t
     * @param c
     */
    public URLImageParser(TextView t, Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        this.container = t;
    }

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

        // get the actual source
        ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = new ImageGetterAsyncTask(urlDrawable);

        asyncTask.execute(source);

        // return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image
        // from
        // the src tag
        return urlDrawable;
    }

    public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable> {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable;

        public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
            this.urlDrawable = d;
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
            String source = params[0];
            fileCache = new FileCache(c);
            return fetchDrawable(source);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
            // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
            urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                    0 + result.getIntrinsicHeight());

            // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
            // from the HTTP call
            urlDrawable.drawable = result;

            // redraw the image by invalidating the container
            URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();

            // For ICS
            URLImageParser.this.container
                    .setHeight((URLImageParser.this.container.getHeight() + result
                            .getIntrinsicHeight()));

            // Pre ICS
            URLImageParser.this.container.setEllipsize(null);
        }

        /***
         * Get the Drawable from URL
         * 
         * @param urlString
         * @return
         */
        public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
            try {
                InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                File f = fileCache.getFile(urlString);
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                os.close();
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                        0 + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());

                return drawable;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        private InputStream fetch(String urlString)
                throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            return response.getEntity().getContent();
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is that if the image coming from html is too big it occupies the whole screen and i need to set the size according to the `width` attribute from the `<img>` tag, or at least set a max size for that image inside this class.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you already knew the solution.
In your code 
`drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                        0 + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());`
Just set the bound of your drawable like this
`drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + MAX_WIDTH,
                        0 + MAX_HEIGHT);`

If you want to scale the image , I think you could do some math there.
Hope this help:)

Comment: Thanks, yup, i solved it some time ago. Using that way and then calculating the screen size.